# Do gases and liquids apply normal force?

Tags: forces

This might be a dumb question but... is it possible for gases or liquids to apply normal force?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Fluids apply normal force on a regular basis.  Typically for fluids we look at the normal force acting over an area; which is called [pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure).  You've most likely at least heard of pressure before, and probably just didn't make the connection between that and normal force.

Comment: And in some circumstances we wrap the pressure in another layer of abstraction and talk instead about the bouyant force...

Comment: @dmckee Very true.  I find that layer specifically is a problematic one.  It seems like _a lot_ of people end up with the misconception that buoyancy is some sort of special force of it's own that automagically acts on objects of different density.  It's really a shame, because the relationship between hydrostatics and Archimedes' Principle is really elegant IMO.  I've seen anywhere from flat earthers to engineers become mislead about how buoyancy actually comes about.

Comment: If liquids and gases do apply normal force, then how do things sink in water or how do gases mix with each other? Shouldnt the normal force prevent things from sinking into water or prevent gases from mixing?

Comment: @RandomGuy Things sink because the normal force isn't enough to stop them from sinking.  That's not always the case, sometimes the normal force is enough that the object floats.  That normal force does actually reduce the net downward force (see [buoyancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy)).  As far as stopping gasses from mixing goes, that can be complicated; but unlike a solid floating on something, it's not like there's an actual hard barrier when gasses meet.  Then concepts like [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion) come into play.

Comment: If the fluid is moving, it can also apply a friction force.